# How do I get Aptana to recognize .jspf files?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, jsp-fragments

How do I get Aptana to recognize .jspf files?

I'd like to have syntax highlighting for .jspf files. I'm sure there's a preference/config option or an xml file to edit, but I'm not finding it.

*I assume it's similar to the eclipse process, so I'm tagging eclipse, too. If it's not, I'll remove the tag.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this is what you mean but you can set your file assosiations in Eclipse usually like this (and yes, Apatana is Eclipse based so it should work the same way):

Window -> Preferences

Then

General -> Editors -> File Associations

Select *.jspf and move or add the Aptana Editor you want to use by default.