# File names for JSP include directive to avoid compilation of them

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

I join to project where code duplication in JSP avoided by **include** JSP directive (static, like #include in C).

Included files follow same naming rules as regular JSP: ***.jsp**

I worry about this. Do they need another file extension to prevent them from compilation by servlet container (they are just only parts of read JSP pages)?

Or servlet container don't touch files if they don't requested?

If I need to use another file extension how to deal with IDE. I don't want to miss syntax highlighting and completion. In case of Emacs it is easy to workaround, but I don't know how to register file type based on file extension in case of NetBeans.

I am not JSP expert so I read *"JSR 267: JSP Tag Library"* section *"JSP.1.10.3 The include Directive"* but didn't find how to resolve my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238594/how-do-i-get-aptana-to-recognize-jspf-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate name for such JSP files is `.jspf` (JSP fragment), as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081005/what-is-jspf-file-extension-how-to-compile-it).

Comment: Thanks! I look to JSF 2.2 spec: *JSP.1.1.8 Naming Conventions for JSP Files* - this is officially documented naming convention. I don't found it as don't read full spec.